# Feature importance or model summary in sktime

Tags: python, sktime

I'm going through the documentation of the `sktime` package. One thing I just cannot find is the feature importance (that we'd get with `sklearn` models) or model summary (like the one we can obtain from `statsmodels`). Is it something that is just not implemented yet?

It seems that this functionality is implemented for models like `AutoETS` or `AutoARIMA`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sktime.datasets import load_airline
from sktime.forecasting.model_selection import temporal_train_test_split
from sktime.forecasting.base import ForecastingHorizon
y = load_airline()
y_train,y_test = temporal_train_test_split(y)
fh = ForecastingHorizon(y_test.index, is_relative=False)

from sktime.forecasting.ets import AutoETS
model = AutoETS(trend='add',seasonal='mul',sp=12)
model.fit(y_train,fh=y_test.index)
model.summary()
```

I wonder if these summaries are accessible from instances like `ForecastingPipeline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve it myself. I'm really glad the functionality is there!

The [source code](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime/blob/v0.10.1/sktime/forecasting/compose/_pipeline.py#L168-L305) for `ForecastingPipeline` indicates that an instance of this class has an attribute steps_ - it holds the **fitted** instance of the model in a pipeline.

```
from sktime.forecasting.compose import ForecastingPipeline

model = ForecastingPipeline(steps=[
("forecaster", AutoETS(sp=1))])
model.fit(y_train)

model.steps_[-1][1].summary() # model.steps[-1][1].summary() would throw an error
```

The output of `model.steps_` is `[('forecaster', AutoETS())]` (as mentioned before AutoETS() is in this case already fitted).